# How does python handle attribute in a class ? Do I always have to initialize them in __init__ method?

Tags: python, oop

I am reading Python 3 object oriented book. And get confused in its code bellow.
The class in the code bellow doesn't have `__init__` method as most of tutorial I searched and suddenly `self.student` appear in method lesson.

```
class IntroToPython:
    def lesson(self):
        return f""" 
        Hello {self.student}. define two variables,
        an integer named a with value 1 and a string named b with value 'hello
        """

    def check(self, d):
        return code == "a = 1\nb = 'hello'"
```

I still can assign value for self.student and it still work as bellow. Does class searchs and allocate all of its attributes when it creates an object without `__init__` method ?

```
b= IntroToPython()
b.student = "John"
```

Comment: BTW, with `b= IntroToPython` you don't create an instance of `IntroToPython` but a second name for the class. You're missing the parentheses: `b = IntroToPython()`.

Comment: I did edit the code, thank for your comment

Answer (score 1):

You can add arbitrary attributes to an instance of a class as shown above, but it probably isn't a good idea generally. In this case, only the object `b` will have the attribute `student`; all other members of the class and the class definition itself remain unchanged. It doesn't make a difference, for example, that you refer to `self.student` in the `lesson()` method; you could define an attribute `b.whatever` whevever you want. This will quickly get confusing though.

It is better to express the attributes and methods that you want in the class in the class definition itself, either in the `__init__()` method or in later 'getter' and 'setter' methods to avoid fiddling with the dot notation and including silent errors, but this is a matter of coding hygeine, not python execution.

Answer (score 1):

`__init__()` is simply a method that is called on the initialization of an object. In Python, the memory of an object isn't fixed at the time of initialization. A Python object is a lot different from a C++ or a Java obect. A Python object can be thought of as closer to a namespace in Python, allowing you to hold a collection of members (functions and values) in it. This collection can be easily extended in Python at any point in the object's lifetime. The object does not hold these members itself, it just maintains references to them.

When you write `{obj}.{name} = {some_val}`, Python checks if the object has a `{name}` attribute. If it does, the attribute is assigned that `{some_val}`, if it doesn't, Python adds the name `{name}` to the object's namespace and initializes it to `{some_val}`. Note that Python doesn't have to create extra space for `name` in the object, it simply has to keep track of a new variable `name` that has been introduced to the namespace (I have described how this happens later). This is because Python's data model is name based, which is different from languages like C++. The space for `name` is allocated elsewhere, `name` is simply a reference to that object.

You can actually see it happening under the hood by using the [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) function. For each object in Python, Python maintains a `__dir__` attribute, which is a list of all names present in the scope of the object. This includes variable names and function names.

So, in your case, if you call `dir(b)` before `b.student = "John"`, you will get this:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'check', 'lesson']
```

Note that this includes a lot of dunder methods, along with the methods `check` and `lesson` that you defined.

After running `b.student = "John"`, we get

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'check', 'lesson', 'student']
```

Note how the name `student` has been added to the namespace of `b` at the end of the list.

So, `{x}.{y}={something}` is a simple way in which the name `y` can be added to `x`'s namespace. After knowing this, it can be seen that `__init__()` functions are not special. They are doing the exact same thing, it's just that `__init__()` is called whenever an object is initialized.

Another interesting thing to note is that since everything in Python is an object (classes and functions are also objects!); so, it is perfectly okay to write something like:

```
>>> def f():
    f.ctr += 1 #f.ctr stores number of times f has been called
    #do something

>>> f.ctr = 0
>>> f()
>>> f()
>>> f()
>>> f.ctr
3
```